# CTTelephonyNetworkInfo's currentRadioAccessTechnology Ambiguous response

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, data-synchronization, cellular-network

I have a scenario in one of my applications that I should allow the user to sync some data to server only if the connection is at least `4G or LTE.` Below is the source code I use and it works fine until the scenario explained below occurs/happens.

```
if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kGPRS;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kWCDMA;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kEDGE;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kLTE;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = YES;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = (NSString *)currentCellularAccessTechnology;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ~= %@",currentCellularAccessTechnology,k4G];
                self.cellularConnectionFast = YES;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ~= %@",currentCellularAccessTechnology,k3G];
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = (NSString *)currentCellularAccessTechnology;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
```

`currentCellularDataConnectionType` keeps current radio access technology and `cellularConnectFast` property determines whether the connection is fast enough.

The issue occurs in the following scenario,

If the user puts the `iPad` to sleep mode by pressing the sleep/power button the `CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification` notification sometimes gives the "`currentRadioAccessTechnology`" property value as `NULL or NIL`. And there is we won't get a second notification with the correct data connection type (`RadioAccessTechnology`) after that. So I cannot set the "`cellularConnectionFast`" property value in that condition.

I tried to implement a logic as to set the "`currentCellularDataConnectionType`" and "`cellularConnectionFast`" property values only if the `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology` value is not `NULL` or `NIL` as given below,

```
if ((NSNull *)currentCellularAccessTechnology == [NSNull null] || currentCellularAccessTechnology == nil) {
            DDLogInfo(@"From %s, New Cellular Connection Type recieved as: %@, so sticking with the previous Cellular Connection Type: %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,currentCellularAccessTechnology,self.currentCellularDataConnectionType);
        }
        else {
            if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kGPRS;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kWCDMA;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kEDGE;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = kLTE;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = YES;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = (NSString *)currentCellularAccessTechnology;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ~= %@",currentCellularAccessTechnology,k4G];
                self.cellularConnectionFast = YES;
            }
            else if ([currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA] ||
                     [currentCellularAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB]) {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ~= %@",currentCellularAccessTechnology,k3G];
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
            else {
                self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = (NSString *)currentCellularAccessTechnology;
                self.cellularConnectionFast = NO;
            }
```

However, I saw comment in the `Raywenderlich` post that there are chances that `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology` can return '`nil`' when the device is not connected to a radio tower.

What is the implementation I can do in this scenario? I use reachability class to identify the current network type (No connection, `WiFi` or `WWAN`) and make the "`currentRadioAccessTechnology`" value calculation only if `WWAN`.

Comment: Have you found a solution for your issue? I have a similar problem: when I put the app into the background and foreground, the `currentRadioAccessTechnology` of an existing instance always returns `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting an instance of `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`, and then calling `currentRadioAccessTechnology` on that ( it is what I do).

The problem comes, exactly as you pointed out when the device sleeps.  The `CTTelephoneNetworkInfo` instance keeps working while your app is running in the background, but as soon as you go inactive; it becomes invalid.

You need to get a fresh instance of `CTTelephoneNetworkInfo` when you become active again ( respond to notification `UIApplicationWillBecomeActive`).

As you pointed out, `currentRadioAccessTechnology` does return `null` when you're not connected to a radio tower, but then reachability won't be returning cellular, so you should be OK.

As a free bonus, the value returned by `currentRadioAccessTechnology` is a string, so you can clean up all those if statements.

Set up reference tables in a dispatch once block

```
NSSet<NSString*> fastTechs = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA, CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPD, CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE, nil];

NSDictionary<NSString*,NSNumber> accessTechTypes = @{ CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA :k4g, CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE : kLTE};
```

Then your regular code looks like :

```
CTRadioAcessTechnology accessTech = telephonyInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology;
self.cellularConnectionFast = [fastTechs contains:accessTech];
```

And

```
self.currentCellularDataConnectionType = accessTechTypes[accessTech]
```