# Swift check network speed

Tags: ios, swift, performance, wwan

I want to check the network speed from my swift application. I have found many posts describing the `Reachability` class specially the way of finding if the connection is reachable or not and if it's a WIFI connection or a WWAN one.

My question: Is it possible to detect the type of the WWAN (2G, 3G, 4G...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're able to check this with [CoreTelephony](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coretelephony). For example:

```
let telInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
if telInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology == CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE {
    // Device has a LTE connection
}
```

You can find a list of all the **CTRadioAccessTechnology** [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo/radio_access_technology_constants).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me please if this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34668588/cttelephonynetworkinfos-currentradioaccesstechnology-ambiguous-response) contains all the WWAN types? Because I searched a lot for a list of all the WWAN types in iOS syntax but I didn't find it

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the list of the constants.

Comment: Look in the header files. They contain the _definitive_ list.