# How to detect whether the connected WiFi is 2.4G or 5G in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, wifi, 5g

How to programmatically determine whether the WiFi that iPhone connected is 2.4G or 5G？

My app needs to know the WiFi information of the current iPhone connected. My app can't perform the next step，When wifi is 5G, then It requires the user to switch to 2.4G wifi to continue. (the 5G here refers to the WiFi that uses the 802.11ac protocol and runs in the 5Ghz frequency band. It is not 5th Generation Mobile Communication Technology)

I tried to use `NEHotspotHelper` to get wifi information, and then determined whether it was 2.4G or 5G, but it failed。So anyone knows how to achieve this function？

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579440/7629882?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, the 5G here refers to the WiFi that uses the 802.11ac protocol and runs in the 5Ghz frequency band. It is not 5th Generation Mobile Communication Technology